# Preloading assets in cocos2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have some assets for my game that are being loaded when the gameplay layer is loaded.  I'd prefer to load them when the application launches in a loading screen, which is obviously a pretty standard thing to do.

My problem is the way in which new scenes are launched within cocos2D.  Consider the following code which occurs (with some variations) in several places throughout the project:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionShrinkGrow transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[GameplayLayer scene]]];
```

This is the standard way of replacing the current scene with a new one.  My question is, given that format, how would I pass a preloaded asset to the new `GameplayLayer`?  Is there an accepted way of doing this in cocos2D?  I have a feeling that I'm missing something incredibly simple, but as of now it's a mystery to me.

Comment: are you using spritesheets or simple images?

Comment: I'm using spritesheets, but the asset that I'm most concerned about is a class I've written myself (i.e. not one that I can load in one scene and automatically use anywhere).

Comment: Beyond asset loading, this has general applications for passing messages and data objects between scenes.  For example, after a level is over, you might load a new scene with a summary of how many points were scored, how long it took, et cetera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocos2d uses a texture cache that persists between scenes. You can preload assets into this cache in a loading scene and they will still be available from your game scene. How you load these are up to you. For images you can opt to do it asynchronously, to allow your loading scene to maintain a decent framerate and render a progress bar.

[This post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1237#post-23820) gets the basic idea across.

This thread may also be of use to you in that regard: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2242

If you have your own class of assets (i.e. not a supported cocos2d image, or something), you could create your own cache singleton class (look at how the sharedManager instances of various cocos2d classes are implemented) and load your assets into that. As far as memory management goes you'd have to release those assets yourself whenever you deem necessary, but that's rather beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I ended up going the singleton route for my custom assets and it works perfectly.  I really appreciate the help.